# match a regex with a dash

Tags: php, regex

I've got this regex below, it works fine for a string that looks like this

```
hello/hi
```

but fails if there is a dash (-) like this `hello/hi-there`

```
if (preg_match('%^(\w+)(/(\w+))?$%', $pathInfo, $matches))
{
   echo 'works';
}
```

also, i would like it to match

1. hello OR
2. hello/hi-there OR
3. hello/hi-there/smile

any idea how to fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just include `-` and space in your regex:

```
'%^([\w -]+)(/([\w -]+))?$%'
```

Comment: I doubt if it actually makes a difference, but I'd just move `-` to either end for safety :)

Comment: Thanks @AmalMurali: I was plain stupid to leave `-` in the middle.